# mount azure file share to web app for linux containers with docker-compose

Tags: azure, docker, docker-compose, azure-web-app-service, azure-web-app-for-containers

I am trying to mount an **azure file share** to a **Web App for Containers (linux)** service.  This is a .net Core 3 web api app with an angular front end.  The app container runs perfectly locally when I mount a local drive to load the exact same files as in the file share.

according to the [docker docs for azure file share](https://docs.docker.com/engine/context/aci-integration/#using-azure-file-share-as-volumes-in-aci-containers) I should set my docker compose file to be the following:

```
version: '3.4'

services:
  webui:
    image: ${DOCKER_REGISTRY-}webui
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: src/WebUI/Dockerfile
    environment:
      - "UseInMemoryDatabase=false"
      - "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Production"
      - "ConnectionStrings__DefaultConnection=Server="
      - "ASPNETCORE_Kestrel__Certificates__Default__Path=/security/mycertfile.pfx"
      - "ASPNETCORE_Kestrel__Certificates__Default__Password=Your_password123"
    ports:
      - "5000:5000"
      - "5001:5001"
    volumes:
       - mcpdata:"/security:/security"
    restart: always

volumes:
  mcpdata:
    driver: azure_file
    driver_opts:
      share_name: sharename
      storage_account_name: storageaccountname
```

In the configuration for my web app I have created the following file mount:
[image]

I can confirm that the file share contains the file referenced in the environment variables: mcpdata/security/mycertfile.pfx

### PROBLEM:

When the container is run by the service it gives an error:

> System.InvalidOperationException: There was an error loading the certificate. The file '/security/mycert.pfx' was not found.

### WHAT I TIRED:

1. Because the container fails I cannot ssh into it to check for the files.  So i pull the image from azure container registry locally and then do a ***docker export -o dump.tar*** .  I then extract the files and the security folder is not created.
2. I also tried just referencing the named file share directly in the docker compose file by removing the top level mount definition from the docker compose file.  removed code shown below:

```
volumes:
  mcpdata:
    driver: azure_file
    driver_opts:
      share_name: sharename
      storage_account_name: storageaccountname
```

### QUESTION:

Can someone help me connect an azure file share to my container, or help me confirm where the files are mounted when the container fails.

### EDIT 1:

attempt to add file share mount with azure cli.  I used the following command to add the file share mount to my web app:

```
az webapp config storage-account add --resource-group "rgname" --name "appname" --slot development --custom-id fsmount001 --storage-type AzureFiles --share-name "sname" --account-name "aname" --access-key "key" --mount-path /
```

this command works and creates the file mount, however I still get the error that it cannot find the cert file in the /security/ folder

If I bash into the app via kudu and not the container itself, I can see that the file mount exists and is named security in the root of the web app.

### EDIT 2: SOLUTION

set up the file mount with the following command:

```
az webapp config storage-account add --resource-group "rgname" --name "appname" --slot development --custom-id fsmount001 --storage-type AzureFiles --share-name "sname" --account-name "aname" --access-key "key" --mount-path /security/security/
```

In docker compose I use:

```
volumes:
   - fsmount001: /security:/security
```

In appsettings.Production.json:

```
  "IdentityServer": {
    "Key": {
      "Type": "File",
      "FilePath": "/security/mycert.pfx",
      "Password": "password"
    }
  }
```

This is what my file mount settings look like in the azure portal under configuration -> path mappings:
[image]

Inside the file mount is a folder called security which contains the cert file.

Thanks to Charles help and I hope this helps someone else!

Comment: `- mcpdata:"/security:/security"` or just `- mcpdata:/security`

Comment: @ThanhNguyenVan `- mcpdata:"/security/security` did not work and neither did `-mcpdata:/security`

Comment: So in the compose file it's just about adding a volume to the service ? (For Azure App Service)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The steps what you have followed is for the ACI, not for the
Web App. To mount the Azure File Share to the Azure Web App for the container, you just need to follow the steps in [Link storage to your app](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-connect-to-azure-storage?pivots=container-linux#link-storage-to-your-app).

And you need to change the docker-compose file at the `volumes`:

From:

```
volumes:
       - mcpdata:"/security:/security"
```

Into:

```
volumes:
       - custom-id:/security/security/
```

The custom-id is the thing you uses in the CLI command.

Comment: how do I get the custom ID of the file share if it has already been created? I tried using he cli and az webapp config storage-account list, but it does not shoe custom id.  Also, when i use the azure cli command to verify storage, it does not work for a deployment slot: "az webapp config storage-account list --resource-group <rg-name> --name <appName/development>"

Comment: adding --slot development got the command to work above.

Comment: @JKing The custom id is the value you use when you execute the command to create the link. You set it yourself. Just need to keep the custom id the same.

Comment: @JKing The mount path in the command also needs to be the same as the docker-compose file. It should be `/security/security`.

Comment: thanks Charles, that last comment was the missing piece, i changed the mount path for the file mount to /security/security/ and the file is getting loaded

Comment: So in the compose file it's just about adding a volume to the service ? (For Azure App Service)