# Mounting One File on Azure Web App for Containers

Tags: docker-compose, azure-web-app-for-containers

I have developed the Multi-Container App and trying to deploy on Azure Web App for Containers using docker compose.

I am able to communicate between the containers created.

In one of the container, we need to mount the **yaml file** to container which docker image name is **aler9/rtsp-simple-server**

I have tried the options provided on below url,

[mount azure file share to web app for linux containers with docker-compose](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64287843/mount-azure-file-share-to-web-app-for-linux-containers-with-docker-compose)

Still Can't able to find out how to configure it.

This is the error shown,

[image]

The docker-compose file as below,

[image]

Comment: It's better send more detail about your docker-compose file or put content of the docker-compose file here

Comment: @xirehat i have added compose file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is you put a space between `:` and destination path `/`.

So change it to:

```
- fsmount001:/path/to/file.yaml
```

Comment: i have tried it this is the error, 

Container create failed for server_0_237c7b90 with System.AggregateException, One or more errors occurred. (Docker API responded with status code=InternalServerError, response={"message":"invalid volume specification: '/var/LWASFiles/Sites/server/<folder>:/': invalid mount config for type \"bind\": invalid specification: destination can't be '/'"}
)

Comment: It is logical, your first issue have been fixed. second issue is related to destination path. you cannot mount your volume to `/` directory. so you should specified destination path which points to the path of the yaml file.

Comment: I have added path for volume and mapped with docker. It worked.